# How to set all Google Chrome notifications act like alerts?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, notifications

According to `Settings > Notifications` there are two types of notifications Banners and Alerts.

```
Banners appear in the upper-right corner and go away automatically.
Alerts stay on screen until dismissed.
```

[image]

I want that all of my Chrome notifications act like Alerts. But they act like Banners. Is there something that I can do to achieve that behavior?

Answer (score 6):

Chrome uses its own type of notifications that aren't necessarily system native - my apologies for the extreme vagueness, I don't know how else to put it. This can depend on whether its a website notification that you can get from an update or one related to chrome itself.

What I believe you are trying to do is force chrome to use native notifications throughout. Try this:

In your search bar input this: `chrome://flags/#enable-system-notifications`. Set this to enable.

Then, under `Setting > Notifications` set **both** the Google Chrome apps to Alerts.

I hope this works.

Comment: Glad it works :) can you mark it as answered please? It helps people find it in future.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work as I expected. Alerts don't stay on a screen and act like banners, they are fading away after a couple of seconds. So, my original problem is not solved.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue as well...  Would love a resolution if somebody finds it!

Comment: It's June 2022 and I still am having this problem. Would love a solution!

Comment: Another June 2022 user here waiting :( I wonder if Safari has the same issue? If not, might be worth switching as the daily driver

Comment: Chrome no longer seems to have this #enable-native-notifications setting, too bad as banner appear and thus are easily missed.

Answer (score 1):

What @Japes said, except looks like the flag name changed at some point to be `chrome://flags/#enable-system-notifications`

Comment: This would be a better answer to say “As of version XXX, the flag has changed to….” and post a complete answer so readers don’t have to reference for the original answer. This could also be an edit to the original answer

Comment: @Allan - I agree that this answer could be fleshed out a little more, however, wrt your second point, if this was edited into the original answer, wouldn't it risk (maybe rightly so) being rejected as an "Attempt to reply"?

Comment: @Greenonline, an edit that is minor like, for version XXX use this “flag” versus a major edit where things are completely different or the edit says “no, this is wrong because” would be a reply.  I usually reject edits that overwrite the original with an update because it removes info that is still valid for some folks.